# Reading txt file in Visual studio 2019 C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to open a file for this program. I have tried pathing it directly using examples like C:\User... but for some reason it still says it can't find the file. I have looked on the internet as well as youtube to open files using C++ and its pretty straight forward. However I still can't get this .txt file to be read. Maybe it has to do with Visual Studio?

```
FILE* in_fp, * fopen();


int main() {
    if  ((in_fp = fopen("TextFile.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        printf("ERROR - cannot open front.in \n");
    else
{
    getChar();
    do {
        lex();
    } while (nextToken != EOF);
}
```

}

Comment: You need to place the file with the executable of your application. Probably in you project folder in a Debug/bin folder.

Comment: Try using the full path for the file.

Comment: You've likely run afoul of the [Working Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)

Comment: Write a temporary file from your "main".  This will tell you where to place your data file.

Comment: Your executable should be in the same directory as `TextFile.txt` otherwise, you'll need to provide the full path.

Comment: If you hardcode the path like `C:\User\TextFile.txt` you need to escape the backslashes in the string literal. Replace each single backslash with two.

Comment: Yes, the IDE matters, the commenters don't use it. Project > Properties > Debugging, "Working directory" setting. The odds that you like $(ProjectDir) are not great in code like this. Although it is a very effective way to make the test data part of the project. Not what you want to do it seems (do consider it), so change it to get ahead